# mysqld check configuration files syntax without applying

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to test changes to the mysqld configuration files before applying them?
I'm thinking about something equivalent to `httpd -t` but for `mysqld`.

This link https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/17/how-to-syntax-check-your-my-cnf-file/ suggests:

```
mysqld --help
error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf at line: 6
...
```

This indeed works however the return code is unchanged and always 0 therefore not ideal to use in a script.

Comment: `|grep -c error`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and I like it, however it doesn't seem to work as it always returns 0.

Comment: thanks redirecting the stderr output beforehand did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the stderr output of `mysql --help` to stdout and you can grep it.

```
mysqld --help 2>&1 | grep -ci error
```

This will result in `0` with no errors and the amount of errors if there are any.

If you want to rely on return codes instead you can use `grep -qi`. It is however a little counterintuitive, since grep will return `0` when it did find the string `error`, and it will return `1` when it did NOT find the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your own code, however one more option hope you are interested to explore

```
mysqld --validate-config
```

If no errors are found, the server terminates with an exit code of 0. If an error is found, the server displays a diagnostic message and terminates with an exit code of 1.

```
shell> mysqld --validate-config --no-such-option
2030-03-31T11:50:12.738919Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--no-such-option'.
2030-03-31T11:50:12.738962Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

One more example

```
shell> mysqld --validate-config
2030-03-31T12:40:02.712141Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'tx_read_only=ON'.
2030-03-31T12:40:02.712178Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

If you want to test my.cnf which is on different path before applying, use like below.

```
shell> mysqld --defaults-file=./my.cnf-test --validate-config
```

Comment: thank you, I've just tested it and it actually starts the process if there's no error which is not desired in my case.

Comment: @8ctopus: If the process starts when you test the configuration, then just stop it again afterwards.  It's not as if you should be /testing/ the configuration on your /Production/ server, is it?  :-)

Comment: @PhillW. the problem is that the process actually starts if the config is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql conf validation well explained in the official blog and documents I have shared it for both 8.0 and 5.7

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration-validation.html
https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/how-to-validate-server-configuration-settings/

Comment: You should add the suggested command directly within your answer so it's visible without clicking through the link.